# Would this fracture treatment work?

Tags: medical

Robin in my story came across an injured monkey. This monkey has a broken leg. Lisa's family is taking care of the fracture. Lisa's mom has X ray vision so she can properly align the bones without actually taking an X ray. Lisa's dad is making the glue for the cast. Lisa is getting the cloth for the cast. And Robin will give the monkey some fruit so that he is distracted from his hurt leg.

Here is how I think they should go about making this cast:

1) Realign the bones properly and wrap the fracture area with cloth, using it like an ace bandage. This should not only keep the aligned bones in place but also help control any bleeding that might be going on at the fracture.

2) Alternate layers of cloth and glue, making sure that the glue has time to dry before the next layer of cloth and glue is put on.

3) Finish with a layer of cloth.

Once the cast is rigid enough, the cast will be on there for several more weeks before it is finally cut off.

But I am wondering if this will work. I mean basically they are making multiple layers of bandaging starting with an ace bandage and I know that this is not how a cast is usually made. Would the ace bandage keep the fracture aligned properly or just control any bleeding? Would the glue ever make it rigid enough for the fracture to be immobilized or just restrict the motion of the fracture?

The reason I am concerned about this is that if the ace bandage doesn't keep the fracture aligned properly, the full cast sure won't. And if the layers of glue and cloth just restrict the motion of the fracture and don't immobilize it, the fracture could get worse.

**So would a cast made from an ace bandage and several layers of cloth and glue(fracture size bandaid basically) actually keep the fracture aligned and immobilized so that it heals properly?**

Comment: "ace bandage", do you mean "ACE™ Brand Elastic Bandages" or it is "ice bandage". Basically you do not necessary need X-ray to fix that - we didn't had X-ray for ages and I bet in that time people had happen to break the bones. Also there are different types of such injuries.

Comment: Off topic. Not about worldbuilding under this site's definition.

Comment: Fruit isn't likely to distract any animal away from excruciating pain.  You'll need to drug that monkey or use brute force in immobilising it.

Comment: @Caters could you please tell us, how are you going to build a new fictional world with this information? I don't say you are not going to, but I just can't see it, and if no one will see it, your question will be put on hold to let you clarify before people start answering.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because It's clearly a plot related point. If it were a question about how people would set bones in a world of nothing but monkeys, glue and ace bandages, or if it were a one person example of a wider issue in your world of monkeys, glue and ace bandages then I could see it, but as it stands this is a question about plot. Perhaps reframe as 'how can people make casts for animals in a world with limited resources'?

Answer (score 3):

Just use a splint.

1. Find a nice piece of metal or wood, cut to the appropriate size.
2. Cut said material to the appropriate length
3. Wrap the material into your ace bandage around the broken limb.
4. [Tape](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=medical%20tape&tbm=shop&*) it up
5. You will want to remove and re-apply every couple of days.

You have to realize, people didn't use casts for...well a long time. And monkeys have never used casts. There is some research on [broken bones in primates](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2328787/pdf/iowaorthj00024-0022.pdf). Turns out they help each other out and heal. Giving a monkey free food and a splint is a better deal than making him hang out in tree while he heals, hoping an eagle doesn't come by.

Answer (score 0):

One can have non-displaced fractures, which are "easy" to deal with, and displaced fractures, which requires reduction before immobilization. 
A though class of displaced fracture is when the bone fragment pierce through muscles and skin, exposing the bone to the outer environment. Here antibiotics are mandatory, to prevent infections. If you have no antibiotics and an exposed fracture you better ampute the broken limb.

In none of these cases a cast prevents bleeding. In all the cases you need to hold the bone still, either by a cast or by a splint (see kingledion's answer)

Comment: But if a cast is able to put enough pressure on the bones to keep them aligned as the fracture heals, then why wouldn't it stop the bleeding? Stopping the bleeding also depends on pressure, be it internal bleeding or external bleeding.

Comment: @Caters, if you stop bleeding it's because you are stopping blood flow. Stopping blood flow for more than few minutes will result in necrosis.

Comment: Sure maybe for a capillary bleed but venous bleeds, although they can resolve on their own, external pressure helps. And arterial bleeds, especially from major arteries like the femoral artery, might not be able to resolve on their own and with an arterial bleed, pressure to stop the bleeding is more important than making sure the tissue is oxygenated. In the case of a major arterial bleed, doctors ligate the bleeding artery and repair it. But without surgery and external pressure, an arterial bleed, if it were to happen would likely mean death from bleeding.